# User permissions/feature limitations of the native zfs smbshare service on linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, samba, zfs, server-message-block

I'm using zfs on *linux*, using the `sharesmb=on` option to try out the native smb share feature instead of adding the zfs tank path to my smb.conf file.

The share has shown up on my windows machines, but my windows users can't write to it.  I think I'm making an assumption that the zfs smb interface is mapping my windows user to a linux user with the same name.  I'd normally make a username map file to map the windows to linux user, but that seems unnecessary since the usernames are identical.

Does the native smbshare even use smb.conf, or are there zfs pool commands that apply samba settings?

Answer (score 1):

ZFS on Linux uses the usershare feature of samba. So to make this work, you have to enable this in smb.conf by defining a directory for storing the usershare definitions

```
[global]
; directory for storing the usershare definitions. permissions
; of the directory govern who can use this.
usershare path = /var/lib/samba/usershares
usershare max shares = 100
usershare allow guests = yes
usershare owner only = no
```

and you have to actually create the directory

```
mkdir /var/lib/samba/usershares
chgrp foo /var/lib/samba/usershares
chmod 1770 /var/lib/samba/usershares
```

now restart smbd.